# Training a YOLO v4 model on a custom data set and the error shown- /bin/bash: ./darknet: No such file or directory

Tags: google-colaboratory, object-detection, yolov4

I  tried to train the custom object according to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yGMZOD44GrI&list=PLv8Cp2NvcY8ATPRk4LycJWr5YWB_svhrW&index=5 and in the training part I get this error.

The training statement I used was:

!./darknet detector train data/piford.data cfg/yolov4-custom.cfg yolov4.conv.137 -dont_show -map

and piford.data is the name of the file.

What should I do?